# MongoDb many to many with big relations

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've read a lot of documentation and examples here in Stackoverflow but I'm not really sure about my conclusions so this is why I'm askingfor help.

Imagine we have a collection Films and a collection Users and we want to know, which users have seen a film, and which films has seen an user.

One way to design this in MongoDb is:

User:

```
{
"name":"User1",
"films":[filmId1, filmId2, filmId3, filmId4] //ObjectIds from Films
}
```

Film:

```
{
"name": "The incredible MongoDb Developer",
"watched_by": [userId1, userId2, userId3] //ObjectsIds from User
}
```

Ok, this may work if the amount of users/films is low, but for example if we expect that one film will have a 800k users the size of the array will be near to: 800k * 12 bytes ~ 9.5MB which is nearly to the 16MB max for a BSON file.

In this case, there are other approach than the typical relational-world way that is create an intermediate collection for the relations?

Also I don't know if read and parse a JSON about 10MB will have a better performance in comparison with the classic relational way.

Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you want to hold the user references in film document? What I wanted to write becomes a small essay on 4 possibilities made up by me which may or may not be true for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For films, if you include the viewers, you might eventually hit the [16MB size limit of BSON documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents), as you correctly stated.

Putting the films a user has seen into an array is a viable way, depending on your use cases. Especially if you want to have relations with attributes (say date and place of viewing), doing updates and statistical analysis becomes less performant (you would need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** your docs first, subsequent **[`$matches`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** become more costly and whatnot).

If your relations have or may have attributes, I'd go with what you describe as the classical relational way, since it answers your most likely use cases as good as embedding and allow for higher performance from my experience:

Given a collection with a structure like

```
 {
   _id: someObjectId,
   date: ISODate("2016-05-05T03:42:00Z"),
   movie: "nameOfMovie",
   user: "username"
 }
```

You have everything at hand to answer the following sample questions easily:

1. *For a given user, which movies has he seen in the last 3 month, in descending order of date?*

   ```
   db.views.aggregate([
     {$match:{user:userName, date:{$gte:threeMonthAgo}}},
     {$sort:{date:-1}},
     {$group:{_id:"$user",viewed:{$push:{movie:"$movie",date:"$date"}}}}
   ])
   ```

   or, if you are ok with an iterator, even easier with:

   ```
   db.views.find({user:username, date:{$get:threeMonthAgo}}).sort({date:-1})
   ```
2. *For a given movie, how many users have seen it on May 30th this year?*

   ```
   db.views.aggregate([
    {$match:{
      movie:movieName,
      date{
        $gte:ISODate("2016-05-30T00:00:00"),
        $lt:ISODate("2016-05-31T00:00:00")}
    }},
    {$group:{
      _id: "$movie",
      views: {$sum:1}
    }}
   ])
   ```

   The reason why I use an aggregation here instead of a .count() on the result is [SERVER-3645](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645)
3. *For a given movie, show all users which have seen it.*

   ```
   db.views.find({movie:movieName},{_id:0,user:1})
   ```

There is a thing to note: Since we used the usernames and movie names, respectively, we do not need a JOIN (or something similar), which should give us good performance. Plus we do not have to do rather costly update operations when adding entries. Instead of an update, we simply insert the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :)